# PreparedStatement to handle/retrieve Null values from Database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Ive been trying to validate values from Database.

so the scenario is,

if my

```
int id=1234;
    PreparedStatement st= null;
Connection con =null;
con=DriveManager.getConnection(//details here);
    String query ="SELECT ID FROM VAULT WHERE NUM=?";
    st= con.prepareStatement(query); <------ NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION
    st.setInt(1,id);
    rs=st.executeQuery();
    while(rs....)
    {
    String checker = rs.getString("ID");
    }
    if(checker.isEmpty() || checker ==null){
    ...//code here
    }
```

PROBLEM: how to handle and store NULL value on the String checker?
how to retrieve NULL value to be used on validation?

Program is stopping on prepareStatement as it is getting NULLPOINTER
Ps:
the query is returning NULL actually, and i need that NULL value for checking. so If it is NULL, i will do INSERT to that table.

Comment: What is `con`? Is it `null`?

Comment: i have my connection established con=DriveManager.getConnection() etc etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `con` must be `null`

Comment: If you're getting an NPE from `st= con.prepareStatement(query);`, then either `con` is `null` or `query` is `null` as of when you make that call. Given the code above, I'd say `con` is `null` because `DriveManager.getConnection()` (sic) is returning `null`.

Comment: Side note: There's no purpose served by having `= null` initializers on your `st` and `con` declarations. In fact, it defeats a useful feature of the Java compiler (an error if you try to use an uninitialized variable).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the query is returning NULL actually, and i need that NULL value for checking. so If it is NULL, i will do INSERT to that table.

Comment: Side note 2: The `|| checker ==null` part of statement `if(checker.isEmpty() || checker ==null)` is in the wrong place. `||`'s operands are evaluated left to right. If `checker` is `null`, `checker.isEmpty()` will throw an NPE. It needs to be the other way around: `if(checker ==null || checker.isEmpty())`. `checker` is also inaccessible where you're using it (outside the `while`), because it's declared *inside* the `while`. I suggest stepping back from your current task and working through some basic Java tutorials and/or a good beginning Java book.

Comment: @JeannellCasaje - No, if you're getting an NPE from the line you said you're getting it from, the query is not returning NULL. The query isn't running at all, because the code has already failed before the call to `executeQuery`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder got it. realized it. thank you